# CSS Horizontal alignment with form fields

Tags: css, xhtml

I have looked at every possible answers on this subject and for the life of me, cannot get it done.

On this page http://dev.rpgplan.com/contact-us/ I am trying to line up the top 3 fields like this image http://note.io/13eOJi7

but all I am getting is misaligned fields.

Comment: You have `<br />` after your spans...

Comment: You also need to add `margin-top:6px` to the third input element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the page you used `<br></br>` tag between 3 input fields that cause lineBreak so here is what i change and think solve your problem

```
<div class="wpcf7" id="wpcf7-f352-p353-o1"><form action="/contact-us/#wpcf7-f352-p353-o1" method="post" class="wpcf7-form" novalidate="novalidate">

<div style="display: none;">
...
</div>

<div id="inner-contact">

<span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap first-name">  
   <input name="first-name" ... " type="text">
</span>
**[Omit <br></br>]**

<span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap last-name">
   <input name="last-name" ... type="text">
</span>
**[Omit <br></br>]**

<span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap email">
    <input name="email" ... type="email">
</span>
</div>
...
</div>
</form>
</div>
```

Also i see your first 2 field has **margin-top: 6px;** and **margin-bottom: 20px;** property but 3rd field has **margin-top: 3px;** and **margin-bottom: 10px;**!
so fix 3rd field's property like two other field and it will be ok.

Comment: Sure enough, the stupid plugin was adding <br> lines in between. You were also right about the margins being added too. I was able to overwrite the styles and all seems ok. thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 0):

maybe this will help,

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MX3ZP/)

```
.small{
    border:1px solid black;
    float:left;
    height:20px;
    width:50px;
    margin-right:20px;
}
.big
{
    border:1px solid black;
    float:left;
    clear:left;
    height:200px;
    width:194px;
    margin-top:20px;
}

<div>
    <div class="small"></div>
    <div class="small"></div>
    <div class="small"></div>
    <div class="big"></div>
</div>
```